# How do SSL certificates come into play with Oauth2 client credentials grant type?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to understand the concepts of oauth2.0's client credentials grant type and SSL certificates.

This is my scenario:

1. I have a web app which will call ABC's API.
2. I am given a client ID and client secret by XYZ.
3. First I make a call to XYZ and send them the client ID and client secret in order to generate an access token.
4. Next, I pass this access token to ABC's API. However, I also have to provide an SSL certificate in my request.

Part 4 is where I am confused. I thought that when XYZ gave me a client secret and client ID, this verifies that I can access ABC's API (and thus the purpose of the access token)? Why do I still have to provide an SSL certificate in order to access ABC's API?

My understanding of SSL certificates is that it is something which proves that my web app is actually my web app. But isn't that the purpose of the access token I received going through XYZ and the oauth2.0's client credential grant type? Or is this just implementation dependant (ie., ABC decided it needed two identity verifications...?)

I'm new to oauth2.0 and SSL certificates in general, so pardon if my understanding is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Had to deal with something similar recently, and found your question by accident.

It is an extra layer of security. For instance, in the EU, in the context of online banking, it's part of the regulation. You can look at the Revolut API for instance https://developer.revolut.com/docs/guides/manage-accounts/get-started/make-your-first-api-request/ . For instance, you have to combine the following info: crypto algorithm, token type, your domain, client id, audit URL, expiration, and so on.

The certificate's private key is encoded in a JWT token, in a process called Client Assertion. Many OAuth2 authentication services use similar mechanisms, especially when dealing with sensitive data, like in the banking business. The server uses this to validate your identity, and make sure nobody stole your secrets.